# Can I just log transform a dependent variable (to remove heteroscedasticity) without transforming the independent variables in a 3 way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity

I'm trying to analyse a data set using an ANOVA but have significant heteroscedasticity - transforming the DV using a log-transformation seems to remove this issue, but I wanted to check if I should also be transforming my IVs for the output to be meaningful? Two IVs are binary, and one is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply logging the DV shouldn't be too much of an issue. Although, it might be worth it to try to see what results you get from using a Kruskal-Wallis Rank Sum Test.

[Refer to this comment for a decent explanation between the ANOVA and Kruskal-Wallis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/76080/123097)