# Is it possible to calculate a confidence interval related to a significant p value from the kruskal wallis test?

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

I have run the nonparametric Kruskal Wallis test with pairwise comparisons in SPSS to understand if my 3 groups of survey participants were different in their responses to a range of 5 point ordinal scale questions (data is not normally distributed).

Some are responses significant at p < 0.05, some are not, as expected and the results fit with our what we expected to find. A particular journal I would like to submit to requires I report 95% confidence intervals with any p values reported, is this possible? It doesn't make sense to me as my understanding of the KW test was it uses ranks of the median. Thanks in advance.

To follow up and provide further information:
I'm now running the Wilcoxon tests in R, this is anexample of an output where p<0.0167 but the confidence interval includes 0 as the CI itself is so small:

> wilcox.test(Data$Max[Data$Cluster==1], Data$Max[Data$Cluster==3],conf.int=T,conf.lev=.983)

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
```

data:  Data$Max[Data$Cluster == 1] and Data$Max[Data$Cluster == 3]
W = 19368, p-value = 0.01348
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
98.3 percent confidence interval:
 -2.390968e-05  4.505737e-05
sample estimates:
difference in location
          6.994035e-06

The data are very skewed! Here is the table of my groups (cluster 1-3) x answers to the question "Max" 1 = Strongly oppose through to 5 = Strongly support

> table(Data$Cluster, Data$Max)

```
  1   2   3   4   5
```

1   1   6  12  38 210
  2   0   6  11  34 103
  3   0   4  10  29  87

Comment: Are you sure they require it in this case?  For coefficients or other parameter estimates, it makes sense, but this is not a parameter estimate.  Perhaps reporting where the 95th percentile of the $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution is as well as the KW test statistic itself would do the job (the $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution is the asymptotic distribution of the KW test statistic under the null hypothesis with $n$ groups.)

Comment: You *can* do what's effective a joint confidence region of location differences, but with three groups you'd be looking at two differences (e.g. G2 vs G1 and G3 vs G1). An example of a joint region is here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76059/difference-between-anova-and-kruskal-wallis-test/76080#76080 ... alternatively you could set up some (marginal or joint) contrasts of interest and plot the acceptance regions for those (which would correspond to confidence intervals). ... ctd

Comment: ctd... If something like that is not what you seek, you'll have to explain clearly what specific quantity you need a confidence interval *for*; is it possible to point to a specific statement by the journal about these requirements? Note that none of the intervals you would generate will be either a confidence interval for a median, or a difference of medians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of this is as follows. If I am wrong, please give the kind of clarification suggested by @whuber, perhaps along with some sample data to illustrate what you are doing.

If the Kruskal-Wallis test rejects
the null hypothesis that the three medians are all equal, then you will
use two-sample Wilcoxon tests to do multiple comparisons A vs B, B vs C and A vs C. In order to control the overall error rate for the three comparisons
you might use the Bonferroni significance level $.05/3 = .0167$ for the
comparisons.

Recently, some psychology and sociology journals have blamed irreproducibility
of certain results on abuse of P-values, and ask for confidence intervals (CIs)
in addition to or instead of P-values. (I'm not saying they are correct to deprecate P-values or that asking
for CIs always makes sense, just stating what I have observed and heard.)

You might give $(100 - 1.67)\% = 98.3\%$ CIs for the differences in medians. Presumably, these could be CIs produced by Wilcoxon test procedures. A difficulty may be that a 5-point ordinal scale might produce some ties, but perhaps the
approximate CIs given in spite of that would be useful.

I doubt that the journal is asking for a CI for the overall
Kruskal-Wallis test, but if so, perhaps use @jbowman's suggestion.

In the tentative exploration (in R) below I use fake simulated data for groups A, B, and C. There are $n = 50$ responses in each group, summarized as follows:

```
summary(A)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.190   2.212   2.935   2.817   3.280   4.700 
summary(B)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.350   2.695   3.450   3.331   4.107   4.690 
summary(C)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.620   3.328   3.800   3.672   4.228   4.690
```

Concatenating the data to the vector `X` and making a group variable `gp`, we
have the following notched boxplot. Notches in the sides of the boxes are approximate nonparametric CIs for individual group
medians, calibrated so that two non-overlapping CIs indicate a significant difference. Roughly, it seems that A and B may differ significantly, that B and C clearly do not, and that A and C are obviously significantly different.

[image]

```
 kruskal.test(X ~ gp)

             Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

     data:  X by gp
     Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 17.887, df = 2, p-value = 0.0001306
```

So there is no doubt that the groups vary. Now we do three 2-sample Wilcoxon
tests. Remember that we are looking for P-values below .0167 in order to declare significant differences.

```
wilcox.test(A, B, conf.int=T, conf.lev=.983)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  A and B
W = 825, p-value = 0.003428
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
98.3 percent confidence interval:
 -1.0200705 -0.1199649
sample estimates:
difference in location 
            -0.5900226
```

.

```
wilcox.test(B, C, conf.int=T, conf.lev=.983)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  B and C
W = 984, p-value = 0.06719
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
98.3 percent confidence interval:
 -0.72004953  0.09001254
sample estimates:
difference in location 
            -0.3000609
```

.

```
wilcox.test(A, C, conf.int=T, conf.lev=.983)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  A and C
W = 537.5, p-value = 9.175e-07
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
98.3 percent confidence interval:
 -1.3099358 -0.5300047
sample estimates:
difference in location 
            -0.9199606
```

Summarizing, we see that A and B are significantly different according to the Bonferroni criterion [CI $(-1.02, -0.12)$]; B and C are not significantly
different [CI includes 0]; A and C are highly significantly different  [CI $(-1.31 -0.53)].$

*Note:* Data were simulated as follows:

```
set.seed(918); n = 50
A = 1+round(4*rbeta(n, 2, 2),2)
B = 1+round(4*rbeta(n, 3, 2),2)
C = 1+round(4*rbeta(n, 3.5, 2),2)
X = c(A,B,C);  gp=rep(1:3, each=n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I managed to get this working and it fits with what I need. Very much appreciate it.

Comment: So to please clarify your answer further, if these tests showed p<0.0167 BUT the CI includes 0, do I then report these as non-significant?

Comment: P-value < 5% seems inconsistent with 95% CI that includes 0. Something seems wrong with that. Sometimes with software implementations of nonparametric procedures the approximation for the test and the aprx for the CI don't match _exactly._ But 0.017 is much below 0.05, so it's hard to believe a 95% CI including 0. What software are you using? Can you show relevant input and output? // Are you using Bonferroni CI's to control family error rate. If so, with K-W, its possible overall test rejects, but that doesn't mean all pairs are signif different.

Comment: I have edited the original question to provide more information

Answer (score 4):

The Kruskal-Wallis test (generalization of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test) is a special case of the proportional odds (PO) ordinal logistic regression model.  You can use the the PO model to get any contrast you need, and even to get simultaneous confidence intervals.  These effects are on the odds ratio scale.  The R `rms` package `orm`, `contrast.rms`, and `summary.rms` functions make these easy to do.